Getting error when uploading file from memory
I am getting an error when uploading a file to the Google Cloud Storage system. I am using the upload from memory operation and using a non-resumable upload. It is a 500 error with no message that is hard to discern what the issue is.
GCP Storage API Documentation being used here: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/7.10.0/File.html#save
Here is the code I am using
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
import { googleStorageClientOptions } from './configuration/credentials';
import { Logger } from './loggerAbstraction';

const googleCloudStorageClient = new Storage(googleStorageClientOptions);

async function storageServiceUpload(fileData: any, log: Logger) {
  try {
    const contents = "this is a string";
    
    let file;
    try {
      file = await googleCloudStorageClient.bucket('bucket_example').file("testfile.txt").save(contents, { resumable: false })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error in file upload', err);
      return null;
    }

    console.log("file", {file})
    return file;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error in file upload', err);
    return null;
  }
}

Here is the error I am receiving back from GCP:
ApiError: Internal Server Error
    at new ApiError (/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/cjs/src/nodejs-common/util.js:114:15)
    at Util.parseHttpRespMessage (/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/cjs/src/nodejs-common/util.js:220:41)
    at Util.handleResp (/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/cjs/src/nodejs-common/util.js:192:30)
    at /node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/cjs/src/nodejs-common/util.js:583:22
    at onResponse (/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:259:7)
    at /node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:157:17
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {

I am unable to find helpful content around what the issue might be, any help would be appreciated!

Go to Cloud Logging and start examining the logs of your project.  If needed, recreate the issue.  What if any messages are logged to Cloud Logging?  What exact statement in your demonstrated code is throws the exception?  If you open up Cloud Shell, are you able to run "gcloud storage cp" command to copy a local file into the bucket?

Added a comment with what I discovered. When creating the storage client, I was using a region specific endpoint while GCP was expecting the general storage endpoint. Thanks for the response!

The issue was the endpoint being used in the credentials for the GCP storage client creation when using service account authorization. I was using a region specific endpoint, while GCP was expecting me to use a general endpoint.
The error logs in GCP had nothing in them due to using this incorrect endpoint.
If you run in to this error, be sure to double check the endpoint you are using for creating your GCP Storage Client.
